# carrierwave + mini_magick gems = not an image error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, image-resizing, minimagick

I'm using:

```
- carrierwave 0.6.0
- rails 3.2.1
- mini_magick 3.4
- ruby 1.9.2p290
```

And during image uploading I want to resize uploading pic:

```
(image_uploader.rb)
process :resize_to_fit => [200, 200]
```

But after image uploading I've got an error:

```
1 error prohibited this organization from being saved:
Image image Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: MiniMagick::Invalid
```

PS. If I'm not resizing, image upload works fine.

PS2. I tried to add in config/environment.rb:

```
require 'rubygems'
require "mini_magick"
```

but without success (still not working - btw. is it required when using mini_magick as a gem?)

Answer (score 15):

I'm sure that you've solved this by now (at least hopefully! It's almost two months later!), but here's a solution that worked for me just now:

---

Uninstall imagemagick through homebrew:

- `brew uninstall imagemagick`

Clean your homebrew directory:

- `brew cleanup --force -s`
- --force removes all out of date keg-only brews, -s removes all cached downloads

Reinstall imagemagick:

- `brew install imagemagick`

---

After all of that, you should be good to go!

Comment: hah! I've solved it but thanks anyway for help! :) btw. isn't homebrew only for mac? I'm on Ubuntu ;)

Comment: @ofcapl Oh man, it is! My mistake! I think I was looking at a similar issue where the person with the problem was using homebrew and I got a bit mixed up... Sorry about that!

Comment: @Ruschill. Works for homebrew installation.  Any idea why this is necessary? Getting the feeling imagemagick is brittle.

Comment: @shajin - sorry but not really - I remember that I've found the solution under the link in my answer but I've found that my answer was deleted by moderator, because the link I provided no longer exists :/

Answer (score 0):

B. Ruschill's answer seemed to have solved many peoples' problem, unfortunately it didn't for me. Nor did many solutions I found on the internets.

Turns out I had an outdated version of `libjpeg`. I fixed that by removing and re-installing using brew. This may happen for other image formats too. Perhaps doing the same for the respective `lib`s might solve the problem.

TL;DR

```
brew remove libjpeg
brew install libjpeg
```