# Carrierwave Error Msg: Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, carrierwave, ruby-1.9, minimagick

I am upgrading my app to Rails 3.2 on Ruby 1.9. I had to drop `attachment_fu`. Carrierwave seemed the obvious replacement. At this stage I am uploading files to the file system (no cloud files, yet).

I am on Lion, XCode 4.3.2, Command Line Tools installed. Running:

```
$ brew doctor
# Your system is raring to brew.
```

I can upload and resize images in this configuration:

- rails 3.1.4
- ruby 1.8.7
- carrierwave 0.5.8
- mini_magick 3.4

I can upload images in the new configuration:

- rails 3.2.3
- ruby 1.9.3 (or 1.9.2)
- carrierwave 0.6.2

(followed by `$ bundle update`) but resizing using `mini_magick` returns this error message:

```
"File Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image Original Error: MiniMagick::Invalid", where File is the carrierwave uploader.
```

The FileUploader contains:

```
include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
def store_dir .. end # the shipped default 
process :resize_to_limit => [500, 600]
```

My Attachment class (with the `mount_uploader :file, FileUploader`) is a parent of `Portrait`, `ReferenceLetter`, and other attachment kind of classes. Each of the attachment classes inherits from the `Attachment`, is `:polymorphic => true`, and `belongs_to :attachable` (User) which, in turn, `has_many :portraits`, `:reference_letters`, etc. `:as => :attachable`.

None of these worked (linked from carrierwave's known issues page):

[Why is this RMagick call generating a segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838307/why-is-this-rmagick-call-generating-a-segmentation-fault)

I didn't want to install ImageMagick manually as suggested here:

[carrierwave + mini_magick gems = not an image error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905499/carrierwave-mini-magick-gems-not-an-image-error)

I'm using Homebrew. Help would be fantastic. Thanks.

Comment: I got it working but forgot to post the solution to here. I believe my problem was a name conflict. My file uploader was called FileUploader. Replacing it with an AttachmentUploader fixed (or so I think) the problem: "File Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: MiniMagick::Invalid"

Unfortunately, I am not 100% certain now, it's been a year ago. If somebody runs into this problem with an uploader called FileUploader and fixes it with a differently named uploader, please confirm it here.

Answer (score 18):

Was fighting with the same error today. The problem was not in mini_magick, the problem is in **DELEGATES** options in your imagemagick

If you run

```
convert -list configure
```

you should have something like this

```
Name          Value
-----------------------------------------------------------------
...
CONFIGURE     ./configure  '--with-bzlib=yes' '--with-fontconfig=yes' '--with-freetype=yes' '--with-gslib=yes' '--with-gvc=yes' '--with-jpeg=yes' '--with-jp2=yes' '--with-png=yes' '--with-tiff=yes' '--disable-shared'
CONFIGURE_PATH /usr/local/etc/ImageMagick/
COPYRIGHT     Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
...
DELEGATES     bzlib djvu fontconfig freetype gvc jpeg jng jp2 lcms lqr openexr png rsvg tiff x11 xml zlib
...
VERSION       6.7.5
```

But in my case key DELEGATES had only xml and zlib values

```
DELEGATES     xml zlib
```

The **solution was** to install imagemagick from source and add params to ./configure

```
1. wget http://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick.tar.gz
2. tar xvfz ImageMagick.tar.gz
3. cd ImageMagick
4. ./configure --with-bzlib=yes --with-fontconfig=yes --with-freetype=yes --with-gslib=yes --with-gvc=yes --with-jpeg=yes --with-jp2=yes --with-png=yes --with-tiff=yes --disable-shared
5. make
6. sudo make install
7. sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib
8. run again "convert -list configure" and look at changes
```

You can find installations instructions for MacOS here http://www.imagemagick.org/script/advanced-unix-installation.php

**UPDATE**

For some reasons, a system can be without jpeg convert libraries. To fix this you can install imagemagick using apt-get or ppa with all needed dependencies or try to install manualy

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62
```

See more info here https://askubuntu.com/questions/211627/how-to-add-support-for-the-jpeg-image-format

**UPDATE 01/26/2013**

To install **libpng**

Follow this link http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html and find "Source Code" block.
Copy a link for a latest version

```
1. wget http://download.sourceforge.net/libpng/libpng-1.5.13.tar.gz
2. tar xvfz libpng-1.5.13.tar.gz 
3. cd libpng-1.5.13/
4 ./configure
5. make
6. sudo make install
7. Rebuild imagemagick
```

Another way to get **JPEG support**

```
1. curl -O http://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsrc.v8c.tar.gz
2. tar zxvf jpegsrc.v8c.tar.gz
3. cd jpeg-8c/
4. ./configure
5. make
6. sudo make install
7. Rebuild imagemagick
```

Comment: Thank you thank you! Was getting the same obscure "Failed to manipulate..." error and couldn't figure it out for hours. I installed ImageMagick using homebrew (I'm on a Mac) and you're solution of installing from source with those options worked like a charm. THANK YOU!!

Comment: Thanks Ivan for the detailed manual install. But I wanted to have it all working with ImageMagick installed via Homebrew, not manually. I did get it work, there is no error messages from MiniMagick. It's almost a year ago, and I forgot to post the solution here and I didn't make relevant notes in my git logs. My best guess: I believe the problem was a name conflict. See my comment to my own question above.

Comment: I've rebuilt ImageMagick from source as per these instructions on top of the IM installed by brew (needed to add JPEG support), everything worked. @Arta I think you should mark this very good answer as accepted.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libjpeg62` worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 11):

**Feb 2014**

I just ran into this issue and was all excited to spend my day compiling ImageMagick from source, but figured I'd try a `brew update && brew upgrade imagemagick` first.

```
==> Upgrading 1 outdated package, with result:
imagemagick 6.8.7-7
```

It worked.

Comment: much easier solution

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your machine has all the compilers and tools it needs.

```
sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
sudo yum install rpmdevtool libtool-ltdl-devel

sudo yum install ImageMagick-devel
```