# After replacing Rmagick with Minimagick, gets 'identify.im6: no decode delegate for this image format' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, minimagick

In my Rails app, I just removed `Rmagick` and added `Minimagick`. Rmagick was too heavy. Things worked fine with Rmagick but in minimagick I get the following error :

```
MiniMagick::Invalid: `identify /tmp/mini_magick20150518-10411-1qz42x8` failed with error:
identify.im6: no decode delegate for this image format `/tmp/mini_magick20150518-10411-1qz42x8' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/544.
from /home/pubudu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mini_magick-4.2.4/lib/mini_magick/image.rb:200:in `rescue in validate!'
```

The file url :

```
[8] pry(main)> file.file.file
=> "/home/pubudu/Projects/istockseller/public/store/photos/thpubs/istockseller-13642162-wallhaven-61582.jpg"
```

The code im trying to run :

```
MiniMagick::Image.read(file.file.file).first
```

Comment: what do you get when you type this into the console: identify -list format | grep JPG

Comment: I get this : ` JPG* JPEG      rw-   Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format (80` Im in Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Looks like [liblqr](http://liblqr.wikidot.com/) wasn't linked correctly. Your application is expecting liquid rescale -- a feature not required by Minimagick. You'll need to rebuild ImageMagick with `--with-lqr=yes`

Comment: @emcconville How can I it? I installed imagemagick from the package manager. But when using Rmagick it works!

Answer (score 6):

Try to reinstall ImageMagick and add `--with-jpeg=yes` to the configuration.

Run `convert -list configure`, and see if you have **jpeg** under `DELEGATES`. If not, [reinstall ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/advanced-unix-installation.php) and add params to `./configure`:

```
1. wget http://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick.tar.gz
2. tar xvfz ImageMagick.tar.gz
3. cd ImageMagick
4. ./configure --with-bzlib=yes --with-fontconfig=yes --with-freetype=yes --with-gslib=yes --with-gvc=yes --with-jpeg=yes --with-jp2=yes --with-png=yes --with-tiff=yes --disable-shared
5. make
6. sudo make install
7. sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib
8. run again "convert -list configure" and look at changes
```

for more information: [Carrierwave Error Msg: Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810356/carrierwave-error-msg-failed-to-manipulate-with-minimagick-maybe-it-is-not-an)

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same thing on my Ubuntu server. However, I solved it by adding `ghostscript` and `libgs-dev` to my Dockerfile `apt-get` lines

```
FROM ruby:2.5.3

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y \
  ghostscript libgs-dev imagemagick
```