# Rails - trying to open a file, but getting MiniMagick::Invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, image-processing, imagemagick

I am trying load a file in controller, like

```
  Avatar.all.each do |avatar|
     if avatar.avatar_file_name
       file = "lib/data/#{avatar.avatar_file_name}"

       image = MiniMagick::Image.open("#{file}")
       ...
     end
   end
```

But whenever I run this code, I get the error message

> MiniMagick::Invalid

I already tried to reinstall the **imagemagick** as is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905499/carrierwave-mini-magick-gems-not-an-image-error), but it didn't really help me.

Where could be a problem? Am I missing a component or something?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should check if file exists first

```
if File.exist?(file)
  image = MiniMagick::Image.open(file)
end
```

To get path to the file you should do something like this:

```
file = "#{Rails.root}/lib/data/#{avatar.avatar_file_name}"
```

btw `lib` is not the best place to save your images.